# Delete word highlighted by search

Tags: search, replace

I have `hlsearch` activated. Sometimes I search for terms I want to correct or delete via `/` and then selecting for the individual instance via `n`. Is there a command to delete the current word on which my cursor is on and which is highlighted via 'hlsearch'? I cannot use `dw` as sometimes the word is part of a camel case or snake case word.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gnd` (or `dgn`) deletes the next occurrence of the last searched term  (deleting at the cursor position if it matches the search). See `:help gn`.

(The hlsearch setting is irrelevant to this command.)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `cgn` can be repeated with `.`, as in `/wrongword<CR>cgnrightword<Esc>......`